# Is it possible to regroup files from multiple directories?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj

I have a c# project with an entity data model with several files regrouped with the DependantUpon tag in the project file.

I wish put the main file in a directory and the others files in a sub directory.

Is it possible to regroup the files if they are not in the same directory?
I tried without success: `<DependentUpon>..\myMainFile</DependentUpon>`